# KDB Query with upper in where clause

Tags: kdb

How to use `upper()` in `where` clause. Below query is giving error:

```
http://kdbserver:5001/?select from table where upper(cola) = `ABC
```

Please suggest how to query

N.B.:Cola is a column

```
http://kdbserver:5001/?select upper(cola) from table <-- is working fine.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `upper[cola]='ABC'`.

Round brackets are not used for function arguments, they are used for precedence etc. Square brackets are used in function arguments.

The reason round brackets worked in the second case is because the parser simply ignored them. Would be the same as `select upper cola from table`

In your first case you have effectively done `select from table where upper (cola='ABC')` rather than `select from table where (upper cola)='ABC'`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with upper[cola]=`ABC and its working :)